# Form helper for creating Radio button in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i am trying to create  a Radio button using Cakephp like the one the result should resemble like

```
         <div data-attr="radio" id="1">
          <label id="label1">Untitled1</label><br/>

          <input type="radio" value="option1" id="Radio11" name="Workexperience"/>
          <label for="Radio11">Option1</label>
         <input type="radio" value="option2" id="Radio12" name="Workexperience"/>
         <label for="Radio12">Option2</label>

        </div>
```

how to generate so using Form helper..
Please suggest me..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might help,

http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements#options-before-options-between-options-separator-a-191

For radio type input the 'separator' attribute can be used to inject markup to separate each input/label pair.

Code View

```
<?php echo $form->input('field', array(
    'before' => '--before--',
    'after' => '--after--',
    'between' => '--between---',
    'separator' => '--separator--',
    'options' => array('1', '2'),
    'type' => 'radio'
));?>
```

Output:

```
<div class="input">
--before--
    <input name="data[User][field]" type="radio" value="1" id="UserField1" />
    <label for="UserField1">1</label>
--separator--
    <input name="data[User][field]" type="radio" value="2" id="UserField2" />
    <label for="UserField2">2</label>
--between---
--after--
</div>
```

Comment: +1. Why was this guy down voted? He takes the time to answer a question and you take points from him? If FormHelper::input() is not flexible enough, use FormHelper::radio(). If that is not flexible enough, write the HTML you need by hand. http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperradio

Comment: I do not believe this method works in Cake 1.3.  Instead, you get a dropdown box.  Better to use the radio() method.

Comment: Use 'type' => 'radio' as Anand stated. That will prevent it from being a select box.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [$form->radio()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/727/radio) should do what you need. I don't know if it will look exactly like your example.