# CakePHP - radio button not showing error message

Tags: cakephp

I'm unable to get the error message to show up when creating a radio form using the CakePHP form helper.

This is what I have now.

```
     $options=array('active'=>'Active','inactive'=>'Inactive');
     echo $form->input('Status', array(
  'type' => 'radio',
  'id' => 'EntryStatus',
  'name' => 'data[Entry][status]',
  'options' => $options
```

));

What am I missing?
I'm using CakePHP 1.2.7 and this is what I have in the validation

```
'status' => array(
    'notempty' => array(
         'rule' => 'notempty',
         'required' => true,
         'message' => 'yo'
         )
    )
```

Tried the answer from [Form helper for creating Radio button in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388823/form-helper-for-creating-radio-button-in-cakephp) and it's giving me a select option form instead.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: How does the validation code you provided relate to the earlier code?

Comment: Is "notempty" case sensitive? The CakePHP web site has it camel cased - not in lower case: http://book.cakephp.org/view/740/notEmpty

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Yes validation seems to work in that if I don't pick anything for the status radio button, it's not inserting the form. The issue I'm having is that, the 'yo' error message, which typically shows underneath the form isn't showing up and that should be built in the form helper.

Answer (score 4):

had same problem, and i fount this, and it works:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/204/Form-Element-Specific-Methods

you need

```
if ($form->isFieldError('gender')){
    echo $form->error('gender');
}
```

... in your code. this works in case that your field is named as gender.

Comment: see also https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/Dt6eqmAQbGA

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I added:

```
<?php echo $form->error('currentStatus');?>
```

below the radio button and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at $form->input('Status' ... (capital 'Status') versus the DB column name (which might or might not be capitalized versus 'name' => 'data[Entry][status]' (not capital 'status').

Cake's form helper is picky about inserting error messages when it can't figure out what things go to what.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the explicit [$form->radio()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/727/radio) method instead of the general input() method?

Comment: Hi @Don Kirkby, yes I tried using $form->radio() method as well. Basically the validation works in that form isn't submitted if the radio button isn't selected. However, the error message that typically shows up below the form isn't showing up and that error message is what I'm trying to figure out since that should theoretically be a built in capability of the form helper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add in an error form helper.

echo $form->error('status');

Answer (score 0):

You need to add error condition in case of radio button

```
<?php 
    $options=array('active'=>'Active','inactive'=>'Inactive');
    echo $form->input('Status', array(
      'type' => 'radio',
      'id' => 'EntryStatus',
      'options' => $options
    )
    );
    if ($form->isFieldError('Status')){
        echo $form->error('Status');
    }
    ?>
```